# How do I add a blank line at end of DataGrid?

Tags: uwp, datagrid, uwp-xaml

I'm working on a UWP application using the DataGrid component on most of my screens.

My customer has a simple request. Many of his users will go into the Windows settings and enable the "Always Show Scrollbars" option. When you do this, the horizontal scrollbar overlaps the last row of a DataGrid and renders it difficult or impossible to see. So the request is to add some blank space there.

Adding padding or margins to the DataGrid component won't work since the scrollbar ends up inside the padding. I tried adding a blank line to the end of the data but there are problems with that approach: sometimes my data objects contain integers or other kinds of fields that will always display as something other than a blank space. Another thing I tried was adding a couple of newlines to one of the text fields in the last line. It looks good at first, but if the user sorts the table by clicking on a column header, then the blank area ends up somewhere in the middle of the table. (Adding a full extra line also exhibits the same problem).

I guess I could work around these problems with custom formatters but that's a lot of work and I have a lot of screens. I'm also worried that the modified list or modified data will end up being written back to a database or exported to a file.

Is there any other solution to this problem?

Comment: You should report this in Community toolkit's gitub: https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/issues